# the reason of only null pointer exception

Tags: spring, exception

I am using spring 2.5 framework.
I am getting such error below.

```
Hata Nedeni :
java.lang.NullPointerException

Hata Mesajı :
java.lang.NullPointerException

Hata Detayı :
```

Error only contain this. It doesn't show any explanation about where exception is taken.  Mostly detailed explanation was shown (especially the controller) however, today only the system gives this exception. 
Thanks in advance,

Comment: provide a full stacktrace

Comment: If you don't see a stack trace it could be because somewhere in your code you are catching the exception and just printing (e.getMessage())